# Determine the angle on the horizontal plane between two sides of the smartphone

Tags: android, geometry, sensors, accelerometer, magnetometer

I'm currently studying sensors in android and I don't quite understand whether it is possible to solve one problem. On my desk there is a drawing approximately the same as in the screenshot. I want to attach the smartphone with both sides (first the top - 1 and then the bottom - 2) and get the angle between them.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COJmz.png)

I tried using a magnetometer and an accelerometer for this, I got a rotation matrix, but it gives the wrong angles when I place the smartphone like in the screenshot. Is there any way to solve this problem?